# How to create named blobs with api responses in foreach loop using Logic Apps

Tags: foreach, azure-blob-storage, azure-logic-apps

I am appending API responses from HTTP requests into array. What I am trying to do is using foreach loop iterate through this array and create blob for each response. How can I set a custom name for each blob?

For example, I would like to create following blobs:

items.json (which would contain json response from 1st request)

location.json (which would contain json response from 2nd request)

...

Thank you for all suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the blob name as you expected in the "Blob name" box of "Create blob" action. You can initialize a variable to store the blob name. If you just have several requests, you can use a "[If condition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-control-flow-conditional-statement#add-condition)". If request 1, set the variable value as "items.json". If request 2 , set variable value as "location.json". Then put the variable into the "Blob name" box of "Create blob" action.

If you have many requests, you can use a array to store the blob names. And use "For each" to loop the names array, put each name of the array into the "Blob name" box of "Create blob" action.

Comment: The first solution is very similar to what I did actually and I'm keeping it as workaround for now. My goal was to create something that would look like your second suggestion.
Is there a way to iterate through 2 arrays at the same time in foreach? Or to refer to a specific item in that array? I'm keeping API responses in one array and I would like to take blob names from the second one.

Comment: @Andy Is there any relationship between the requests and the nameList ? Are they key-value pair relationship ? Or just use the first name of the nameList as the name of first request, use the second name of the nameList as the name of second request..... ?

Comment: @Andy And could you please share some screenshots and details of your current logic app ?